# passing data to dynamicaly created siblings

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I am struggling to get the answer to a what I think is an simple question, without success. I'm new to Vue.

**Description:**
Let's take the use case of a "dot navigation" of a website. This will be a component (DotSideNavi) which will render with a v-for loop 4 "dots" components (DotNaviElem).

**Actions:**
When clicking on one "dot",

1. all others need to be deactivated(remove active class) and
2. the clicked one need to be activated right after

**Try and Fail:**

1. I tried using the `$emit` and `$on`, both at the "dot" el, so when clicking on one "dot" I was expecting the event to be passed to all the 4 "dots". Instead, the event was triggered 4 times for the same "dot" el only.
2. `Vuex`: Tried do implement the same logic, but again the state was changed only for the clicked "dot"
3. Passing data back and forth from child-parent-child is considered a bad practice
4. Identifying each dot and using that to deactivate them seems like the wrong way to solve this.
5. From what I read about `slots`, they seem not relevant

**Code (simplified):**

```
<!-- Side Dot Navi -->
<template>
    <div class="dot-side-nav">
        <dot-navi-elem v-for="(n, index) in 4"
                       v-bind:key="index"
                       v-bind:class="{ 'active': index === 0 }" <!-- just dummy init for activating first dot -->
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import DotNaviElem from '~/atoms/DotNaviElem.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            DotNaviElem
        }
    };
</script>

<!-- Dot Navi Element used for Side Dot Navi -->
<template>
    <span class="dot-wrapper "
          v-bind:class="{ active: isCurrentSlide}"
          v-on:click="activateDotNaviElem()"
    >
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isCurrentSlide: false
            };
        },

        methods: {
            activateDotNaviElem() {
                this.isCurrentSlide = !this.isCurrentSlide;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

**Requirements:**
no other external libraries are allowed..

**Framework:**
Nuxt, Vue, Vuex

**Question**:
Can somebody explain me what's the "vue" way to code this and point me to the right resources? This has to be simpler than it looks now.

**Bonus:**
I would appreciate a quick explanation on why 1. and 2. (Try and Fail) are not triggering events/state changes for all the "dot" components?

**Repository**
You can find in the following repository, a project with this example included:
 https://github.com/stavros-liaskos/nuxt-fun
Relevant files:
components/DotSideNavi.vue (navigation)
atoms/DotNaviElem.vue (dot element)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Borjante I edited my original post to include an example of the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go.

https://jsfiddle.net/Critycal/rn4mL0n4/

You first aproach with events was the correct one.

Take a look at the events section in the VueJS docs.

```js
Vue.component('dot-navigation', {
 data() {
   return {
     index: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<div><p>{{ index }}</p><dot-navigation-element v-for="(n, index) in 4" v-bind:key="index" v-on:test="setActive" :index="n" /></div>' ,
  methods: {
   setActive(index) {
     console.log("sdf")
     this.index = index
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('dot-navigation-element', {
 props: ['index'],
  template: '<span v-on:click="activate">dot</span>',
  methods: {
   activate() {
     console.log("activate");
     this.$emit('test', this.index)
    }
  }
  
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <dot-navigation></dot-navigation>
</div>
```

Updated JSFiddle 
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/Critycal/rn4mL0n4/9/)

Comment: As far as I understand, in the above snippet, the parent (dot-navigation) can identify which child (dot-navigation-element) is clicked but will not deactivate the rest of them, which is actually the expected result.

Comment: Now you would just need to pass down to the elements the active index, and then, each element will have to check if their index is == to the active element.